# Using pause with a NSTimer but the gap is too big Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, nstimer, scene

My last bug before uploading (Fingers Crossed). I am using a NSTimer and then invalidate it when I have paused the game. However, when it resumes it gives a larger gap. If I comment out the invalidate and just use the `scene!.view!.paused = true` code then gives me a shorter gap.

I may be able to do it differently but I want to try and find the solution for this. I have learn this way and am comfortable with it.

```
        if touch.name == "pause" {
            pause.hidden = true
            play.hidden = false
            timer.invalidate()
            scoreTimer.invalidate()
            scene!.view!.paused = true
        }
        if touch.name == "play" {
            pause.hidden = false
            play.hidden = true
            scene!.view!.paused = false
            scoreTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.1, target:
self, selector: #selector(GameScene.updatescore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.5, target:
self, selector: #selector(GameScene.makeTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are meaning Eric? I am new to this. I have declared them else where in the code. I found this resume/play code a way to work

Comment: You are using SpriteKit right? Use `update(_:)` method in `SKScene` instead.

Comment: For your approach, did you use any variable to keep track of the time since last update?